# How to add a link within a div using a PHP function?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function

My Wordpress theme has a slider built-in, which allows for a slider Header & a Description via Wordpress Menu > Appearance > Customise. However the input boxes for the Header & Description do not acknowledge code. So I cannot simply add a link or a button in the description input box using something like `<a href="#IngredientsAnchor">Click Me!</a>` or `<button type="button" onClick="#IngredientsAnchor">Click Me!</button>` etc.

**Here is the code for the slider**

```
<div id="main" role="main">
    <section class="slider">
        <div id="slider">
            <ul class="slide-img slides">
                                        <img alt="slide1" src="http://mastermix.asia/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/cow.jpg">   
                                        <div class="container caption-overlay text-right">
                                                <h1 class="slider_txt">
                        Master Mix                      </h1>
                                                <div class="txt">
                        <p>The very best of animal feed!                            
                        </p></div>

                    </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

**And I would like to use a function to add in the line so that it displays something like this:**

```
<div id="main" role="main">
    <section class="slider">
        <div id="slider">
            <ul class="slide-img slides">
                                        <img alt="slide1" src="http://mastermix.asia/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/cow.jpg">   
                                        <div class="container caption-overlay text-right">
                                                <h1 class="slider_txt">
                        Master Mix                      </h1>
                                                <div class="txt">
                        <p>The very best of animal feed!                            
                        </p></br><a href="#IngredientsAnchor" class="button">Click Me!</a></div>

                    </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Can someone advise on the function I would require to add in the line required?

Many thanks.

***EDIT:*** I may possibly require a 'working' function similar to this that I have come up with. Can someone advise? Or amend so that this would work?

```
function replace_slider_txt()
{
    $(".txt").replaceWith('<div class="txt"><p>The very best of animal feed!</p><br /><a href="#IngredientsAnchor" class="IngredientsBtn"></a></div>');
}
add_action('slider','replace_slider_txt');
```

***SECOND EDIT:*** I have also tried breaking out of php in my functions.php and using script to do the edit which also displays no change. **GRRR!**

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.txt').replaceWith("<div class='txt'><p>The very best of animal feed!</p></br><a href='#IngredientsAnchor' class='IngredientsBtn'>&#x2B07;</a></div>");
</script>
<?php
```

***THIRD EDIT:*** I have also tried a simple CSS code to maybe change it this way as a last resort. Still no change to the actual front page

```
.txt,
.txt p { content: 'HAVE I CHANGED??' !important; }
```

Using Chromes Inspector and clicking on the `.txt` I cannot see the new *element* content, but it exists in the *styles* column only. So no good for what I require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add following piece of code in your custom js file of theme.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery( "#slider .txt" ).append( '</br><a href="#IngredientsAnchor" class="button">Click Me!</a>');
});
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't do anything. I tried placing this snippet inside custom.js within my child-theme folder, and I also tried in the custom.js parent theme.

Comment: Can you place it and check again after clearing cache of browser?

Comment: I tried with Chromes incognito after clearing cache. Still no change

Comment: Can you keep added code at your custom js file ? http://mastermix.asia/wp-content/themes/spasalon/js/custom.js

So i can see element is displaying at here http://mastermix.asia/ or not

Comment: Your solution did work, many thanks. The SpaSalon Theme also has its own DreamSalon sub theme, which I put the code you gave in the sub-theme which didn't work. Although it does work in the parent theme. But I can amend this in my child-theme.